# String Format Output Console vs GUI

Tags: java, string, format, textarea

I am trying to print a formatted String to a TextArea, however the output is not formatting correctly. It is formatted correctly when printed to the console however. Is there anything different about TextArea that I need to consider when writing output?

Answer (score 0):

You might get unexpected results if the TextArea isn't using a fixed width font or if the TabSize property isn't the same as console and you have tab characters in your string.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that.